# Powering a robot using the 12v adapter

Tags: battery, power

Hello every one hope you all alrigt

I am working on a mecanum wheel robot and now I am facing a problem to afford a lipo battery which the required voltage to power my robot is 12 
So I think that I can exploit the 12v adapter to power my robot and I want to know if its possible or no

First I have a cotroller which takes a rated voltage 6v - 12v and rated current 1.5 A

And tow motor drivers with driving voltage of 6 - 12 v and driving current of 8A

My idea is to take an adapter like this one 
[image: 12v 2A adapter]

And connect in parallel with these three chips to power my robot 
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check how much current your power adapter can draw.

If i understand correctly, you need at least 12v 9.5A to make your robot work. (~8A+1.5A).

The kind of power adapter you showed on the picture generally does not provide this much current.